# Problem in Wordpress site's Header background image on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am helping a friend on his website and I see there is an overflow-x on his website when viewing on mobile device. I am fairly new at WordPress and I am trying to help him due to having HTML background.

He is currently using the Ocean Wp Theme, tho I have no idea what is causing the website to create this overflow I would appreciate any help you can give me.

[image: Attached image with background showing]

Comment: Its hard to say, but can You provide link for the site ? 
This bug usual cause if one element\div on page are bigger than others or have more than 100% width.

Comment: I agree, quite hard to determine what causes the overflow especially with templates - the site is http://www.fitnessfanatixpts.co.za/

Comment: your site not working

Comment: It works for me, I checked on all browsers

Comment: the site does keep timing out > www.fitnessfanatixpts.co.za took too long to respond. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT > but im not seeing the same overflow issue, and the background is set to cover [which is good, its telling it to cover the whole screen]. Its really not the best made ready to use theme [most arent to be fair for various reasons]. its possible that background-attachment:fixed;  is being a problem child [it doesnt work on IOS devices] for example.